# HTML, CSS, floated image margins?

Tags: html, css, css-float

When I have code like this:

```
<p>
     Some long text
     <img src="src" style="float: right" />
     the rest of the text
</p>
```

I'm getting the strange red areas shown below. How to avoid that? Both p and img have no margins and paddings (in the picture above img has 5 px left and bottom margin).

[image: Image Float Problem]

Comment: Short of seeing the rest of the CSS I can't really help. But perhaps you should try explicitly setting `margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` in there?

Comment: I believe that's strange default behavior. Img has no margins and paddings, just like paragraph. Even if paragraph will have margins and paddings it should affect text and image both since they're a part of the paragraph together.

Comment: have you tried with this <img src="src" align= "right" />

Answer (score 3):

For the first red area, I have no idea what's going on without seeing the full HTML and CSS. The second red area (underneath the image) can't be removed. Your browser can't position any text close enough to the image, so it leaves that gap instead.

Comment: Floated elements are automatically block elements.